# How to display a Zurb Foundation sticky menu that is overflowing on small screens?

Tags: screen, media-queries, zurb-foundation, sticky

I'm using `Zurb Foundation 4.0.9` and I'm using the `.sticky` top-bar menu. It works well on large screen devices.

But when I use the sticky menu on **small screens**, there are so many items in my menu that the bottom of it overflows and I cannot get it into the screen (because of the sticky property).

The easiest answer is to create two menus, one that is sticky for large screens and one that is fixed for small screens but then I'll have duplicate markup. Is there another way ?

**EDIT:**
I'm using the code of the [Top Bar](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/top-bar.html) provided on the Zurb Documentation. The problem arises when the menu is *expanded* vertically. Some of it is overflowing.

**EDIT2:** Here is the visual rendering of the problem : [Screenshots](http://postimg.org/image/e28fd9o5l/)

Thanks for your answers !

Comment: Are you trying this on a desktop browser? If yes, then you would not be able to try it like that and it's because you do not have the "swipe" capability on your browser. You need to install an emulator like Ripple that you can [get from here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ripple-emulator-beta/geelfhphabnejjhdalkjhgipohgpdnoc?hl=en) and test your application with it. It (still) works by the way.

Comment: Yes, I'm showing this using my desktop Chrome Browser because the Chrome Browser on my smartphone (Nexus 4) is behaving exactly the same... And it's up to date, I don't understand what I'm missing...

Comment: Hmm, that's odd. I tried the code I gave you below and added a lot more menus and I can scroll through them, using Ripple, tested on different devices. I can't test it on a server right now so I can't be of further help tonight.

Comment: I can reproduce the same problem in Ripple with the WebWorks v2.0.0 platform with a Blackberry Bold 9700 in portrait mode... This is really strange. Thanks again !

Comment: Obviously since there are inconsistencies, seems like not all devices supports a long list of menu, better report this as a bug.

Comment: Thanks again, I'll post this on their issues list !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the answers and comments, it seems this is a Zurb Foundation 4.0.9 **bug** (inconsistencies across devices but still reproducible).

Answer (score 0):

It's best to use the [Top Bar](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/top-bar.html) as it will handle the resizing and toggling of elements (navs) for you. Here's a code I borrowed and simplified from the doc page of Foundation:

```
<div class="sticky">
    <nav class="top-bar">
      <ul class="title-area">
        <!-- Title Area -->
        <li class="name">
          <h1><a href="#">Top Bar Title </a></h1>
        </li>
        <!-- Remove the class "menu-icon" to get rid of menu icon. Take out "Menu" to just have icon alone -->
        <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span>Menu</span></a></li>
      </ul>

      <section class="top-bar-section">
        <!-- Left Nav Section -->
        <ul class="left">
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Main Item 1</a></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#">Main Item 2</a></li>      
          <li class="divider"></li>
        </ul>

        <!-- Right Nav Section -->
        <ul class="right">
          <li class="divider hide-for-small"></li>
          <li class="has-dropdown"><a href="#">Main Item 3</a>

            <ul class="dropdown">
              <li><label>Dropdown Level 1 Label</label></li>
              <li class="has-dropdown"><a href="#" class="">Dropdown Level 1a</a>

                <ul class="dropdown">
                  <li><a href="#">Dropdown Level 2a</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Dropdown Level 2b</a></li>                  
                </ul>
              </li>          
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li class="has-form">
            <form>
              <div class="row collapse">
                <div class="small-8 columns">
                  <input type="text">
                </div>
                <div class="small-4 columns">
                  <a href="#" class="alert button">Search</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
          </li>
          <li class="divider show-for-small"></li>
          <li class="has-form">
            <a class="button" href="#">Button!</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </section>
    </nav>
</div>
```

The key here is that you need to wrap the navigation inside a `sticky` div, which I think you already know, and a `top-bar` class on the nav element. If you do that Foundation will take care of the rest for you. To understand how the menus are hidden on smaller screens, a height of 45px is applied to it, the same height that the entire nav has. When you click on the menu icon an `expanded` class is applied to the `nav` so you can see your menus.

Comment: Thanks @von-v but I'm already using the Top Bar menu. The problem comes when it expands and the screen is too small to show the whole menu... It works well with non-sticky menus because you can scroll, but it doesn't work when it's sticky (it overflows).

Comment: It works on mine, best that you provide in your question what you have.

Comment: I've added a screenshot in the question to better describe my problem. Thanks for your help.